# Why does location of inStream.Close(); matter?

Tags: .net, windows, jpeg

Why does this code work

```
    Stream inStream;

    private void ResizePoster(string jpgFileName)
    {
        // Ideal poster size is 299×434 at 100% quality
        const int idealWidth = 299;
        const int idealHeight = 434;

        BitmapSource srcImage = DecodeJpg(jpgFileName);
        if (srcImage.PixelHeight > idealHeight || srcImage.PixelWidth > idealWidth)
        {
            float xScale = (float)idealWidth / srcImage.PixelWidth;
            float yScale = (float)idealHeight / srcImage.PixelHeight;

            float scale = Math.Min(xScale, yScale);
            TransformedBitmap scaleImage = new TransformedBitmap(srcImage,
                                        new ScaleTransform(scale,
                                                           scale,
                                                           0, 0));

            FileStream outStream = new FileStream(@"F:\Out.jpg", FileMode.Create);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(scaleImage));
            encoder.Save(outStream);
            outStream.Close();
            inStream.Close();
        }
    }

    private BitmapSource DecodeJpg(string jpgFile)
    {
        // Open a Stream and decode a JPEG image
        inStream = new FileStream(jpgFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(inStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
        bitmapSource.Freeze();
        return bitmapSource;
    }
```

But not this code?

```
    Stream inStream;

    private void ResizePoster(string jpgFileName)
    {
        // Ideal poster size is 299×434 at 100% quality
        const int idealWidth = 299;
        const int idealHeight = 434;

        BitmapSource srcImage = DecodeJpg(jpgFileName);
        if (srcImage.PixelHeight > idealHeight || srcImage.PixelWidth > idealWidth)
        {
            float xScale = (float)idealWidth / srcImage.PixelWidth;
            float yScale = (float)idealHeight / srcImage.PixelHeight;

            float scale = Math.Min(xScale, yScale);
            TransformedBitmap scaleImage = new TransformedBitmap(srcImage,
                                        new ScaleTransform(scale,
                                                           scale,
                                                           0, 0));

            FileStream outStream = new FileStream(@"F:\Out.jpg", FileMode.Create);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(scaleImage));
            encoder.Save(outStream);
            outStream.Close();
            //inStream.Close();
        }
    }

    private BitmapSource DecodeJpg(string jpgFile)
    {
        // Open a Stream and decode a JPEG image
        inStream = new FileStream(jpgFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(inStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
        bitmapSource.Freeze();
        inStream.Close();
        return bitmapSource;
    }
```

The only difference is the location of inStream.Close(). I would much prefer to use the second over the first so that I can make Stream inStream; a method variable instead of a global class variable.

I get no errors, but the generated jpg file does not have the right content. It's of the right dimensions and can be opened as a jpg but the image is complete garbage. I'm using .NET 4 Client Profile, if that matters.

Here are the two generated images so you can see for yourself:

[image: Good out]

[image: Bad out]

Comment: Normally you shouldn't be manually calling Close on Streams explicitly. You should be wrapping them (and all `IDisposable` resource for that matter) in `using` statements.

Comment: The value of the 3rd argument of the JpegBitmapDecoder constructor matters.   From the docs: "Use the OnLoad cache option if you wish to close the bitmapStream after the decoder is created".

Comment: Hans, thank you. Using BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad instead was the key.

Darin, if I don't close the streams both the input and output files are left open on disk. Since eventually the routine will be processing 700 posters, I don't want 1400 file handles left open.

Comment: If you use a `using` statement, then the stream will auto-close when the statement ends.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I implemented using statements in the code and it works well.